# Is it possible to use fork without exec if both processes are executing the same program?

Tags: c, fork, exec

Here is a code sample where the `fork` library call is used to create a child process which shares the parent's address space. The child process executes its code without using the `exec` system call. My question is: is the `exec` system call not required in the case that both the parent and child processes are executing the same program?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
      int count;
      count = fork();
      if (count == 0)
          printf("\nHi I'm child process and count =%d\n", count);
      else
          printf("\nHi I'm parent process and count =%d\n", count);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible and fairly common.

Comment: Nowhere is it written that one must `exec` after `fork`ing. This strongly implies that you absolutely can `fork` without calling `exec`. Therefore, it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Well... just because the answer to the question is obvious doesn't mean that it is unclear what the question is.

Comment: The answer is "Yes". Unless you can show why that is a problem, there is nothing more one can add as an answer.

Comment: BTW, your variable name makes no sense: `count=fork();` The return value of `fork` is in no way a "count" of anything.

Comment: Also, `fork()` doesn't reutrn an `int` but a `pid_t` so the correct type of the return value is `pid_t` and naming it `count` is certainly not a good thing.

Comment: (Just) forking a multi-threaded application can indeed become tricky.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question may be different depending on the operating system. The man page for `fork` on OS X contains this ominous warning (bold portion is a paraphrase of the original):

> There are limits to what you can do in the child process.  To be
>   totally safe you should restrict yourself to only executing
>   async-signal safe operations until such time as one of the exec
>   functions is called.  All APIs, including global data symbols, in any
>   framework or library should be assumed to be unsafe after a fork()
>   unless explicitly documented to be safe or async-signal safe.  If you
>   need to use these frameworks in the child process, you must exec.  In
>   this situation **it's reasonable to exec another copy of the same executable**.

The list of async-signal safe functions can be found in the man page for *sigaction(2)*.

Comment: Would it be possible to link the relevant documentation?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18854708/694576 It seems the restriction you are pointing to is limited if using OSX specific features.

Comment: Gotta echo @alk's question here: The highlighted bit doesn't have any Google hits other than this post; [Apple's online documentation doesn't have `fork`](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=fork&type=Documentation), and that verbiage isn't found in [the FreeBSD manpage](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?fork%282%29). What's the source for that quote?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Open a terminal window on a Mac, and type `man fork`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use fork without exec

Yes, it is possible.

> is the exec system call not required in the case that both the parent and child processes are executing the same program

Yes, it is not required in that case.