# Making multiple processes on same local machine communicate to each other using C sockets

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, client-server, fork

I am working on my semester project in which i have to simulate multiple processes on a single computer (number of processes is entered by user) that do some useful computation in a distributed manner and communicate to each other using C sockets. I will use fork() system call to create as many processes as user want to create.

Here in the code I am trying it on two processes. Here a process creates the other process using fork() and then they try to communicate to each other. Each process(P0, P1) will have a server thread and a client thread. P0's clent will send a message to P1's server and P1's client will send a message to P0's server. Here is my code.

```
int arr_of_ports[3]={7000,7001};
int P_ID;
void *server(void *i)
{
   int sockfd, newsockfd=-1, portno, clilen;
   charenter code here buffer[256];
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;    
   int  n;
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);                                             
   if(sockfd < 0) 
     {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");                
        pthread_exit(NULL);
     }
   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));      
   portno = arr_of_ports[P_ID];                                      
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");    
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);                     
   if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)< 
   0)  
   {                                                                         
      perror("ERROR on binding");
      pthread_exit(NULL);
   }
   listen(sockfd,5);                 
   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);        
   printf("P%d server waiting for incoming connections \n",P_ID); 
   newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, (socklen_t 
   *)&clilen);
   printf("server side : connection accepted \n");
   bzero(buffer,256);
   n = read( newsockfd,buffer,255 );
   if (n < 0) 
     {
        perror("ERROR reading from socket");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
     }
   printf("P%d received message: %s\n",P_ID,buffer);
   close(newsockfd);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *client(void *i)
{
  int *p=(int*)i;
  int to=*p;
  int port_no;
  int client_socket;
  int status=-1;
  char buffer[100]="hello I am ";
  char c=P_ID+'0';
  buffer[11]=c;
  buffer[12]=0;       //to send message like 'hello i am 1' 
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
  if((client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {   
      printf("socket not created\n");
      pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
  port_no=arr_of_ports[to];      /* gives the server thread a port 
  number according to the ID of its process*/
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(port_no);
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  printf("P%d client trying to connect to server \n",P_ID);
  int atmpt=0;
  status = connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, 
  sizeof(server_addr));
  if(status < 0)
    {
      printf("error connecting to the server \n "); 
      pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
  else
    {
      printf("P%d client connected to server",P_ID);
    }
  write(client_socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
  close(client_socket);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
```

}

```
int main()
{
  pthread_t t[2];
  int flag=1;
  int count=0;
  for(int i=1;i<2;i++)          //creating one more process
  {
  if(flag>=1)
    {
      flag=fork();
      count++;
       }
   else
     {
       break;
     }
 }  
 /*gives the processes an ID so that their server thread can be bound 
to a port such that the other processes know this server's port*/
if(flag==0)
  P_ID=count;     
else
  P_ID=0;
int rv=pthread_create(&t[0],NULL,server,NULL);  // server thread
int tc=1;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
  if(i != P_ID)
   {
     int rv=pthread_create(&t[tc],NULL,client,&i);   /*i is the 
   process to which the message is to be sent*/
     tc++;     
   }
}
printf("main thread exited \n ");
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Although, the code seems to be fine, but the clients never connect to server. Clients does not connect to server and the process does not terminate. Here is the output that I get every time.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGqJm.png)

If anybody bothers to answer, that will be a great help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: forking is not creating a thread... are you asking for inter __process__ communication, or inter __thread__ ?

Comment: In most cases, the child process should call one of the `exec` functions after the `fork`. Here's an excerpt from the man page for `fork`: *"There are limits to what you can do in the child process.  To be totally safe you should restrict yourself to only executing async-signal safe operations until such time as one of the `exec` functions is called."* In particular, none of the calls to the socket API are async-signal safe.

Comment: `pthread_create(&t[tc],NULL,client,&i);` you are passing the address of a local variable to a new thread and dereferencing it inside while the parent thread might exit by then (or change the value of `i`). I suggest, `malloc`ing the buffer to pass `i` in and free it inside the client thread after derefencing it.

Comment: @user3386109: Could you post a citation? The POSIX documentation for [fork](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fork.html) and [signal-safety](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) would suggest you are completely wrong on both counts.

Comment: @EOF that's from Mac docs (which I cannot view, naturally). I remember from Python issue database that even some socket calls in Mac create threads that will cause UB if forked...

Comment: @EOF ah no, that's from *iOS*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854708/why-is-it-prohibited-to-use-fork-without-exec-in-mac/21177928

Comment: In any case, `pthread_create` with `fork` is a big nono!

Comment: This comment thread has gone out of control. There's absolutely nothing wrong with doing a `fork` and then having each process do `pthread_create`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, doing `pthread_create` and then having a thread do a `fork` must be done with care. But, OP does the `fork` first, so each process acts alone, so doing `pthread_create` in each one is fine.

Comment: @KunalJon One issue: When you create the `client` thread, you're passing it a pointer to a local stack variable. That stack variable is changing (because you use it as the loop counter). So its value is unstable. But worse, at the end of the loop it goes out of scope and so is not guaranteed to exist any longer. Besides all that, the main thread may exit before the threads even get a chance to start (and the implementation would be within its rights to destroy the main thread's stack when that happens). Just use `(void *) i` as the thread function argument if you're just passing an index.

Comment: Also, the whole thing seems unnecessarily complicated. You have exactly two processes, each of which has a server thread and a client thread. The only thing you need to do is swap the ports. Set a single flag after fork, telling you whether you're parent or child. Use that flag as the port selector in both parent and child. In parent, flag=0, in child, flag=1.  In server thread, listen on `arr_of_ports[flag]`. In client thread, connect to `arr_of_ports[!flag]` -- note that complementing (with `!`) inverts the value (`!0 == 1`  and  `!1 ==  0`).

Comment: The first thing you need to decide is the [topology of the network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_topology#Star). That will drive many of the other design decisions, and ultimately determines how complicated the implementation is.

Comment: thanks @GilHamilton. The only problem was that once the main thread exited, its local variables were destroyed. After Solving this the code runs properly. Thanks once again.